# Exclude WCF service reference from being included in Code Coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, devops

I have a WCF service reference in .net Core 3.1 application. I can apply [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute, but class is created every time I update the reference. I am using [Coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet) for collecting Code Coverage data while building.

I saw in this [post](http://badecho.com/2012/03/excluding-code-coverage-with-postsharp/) that I can put
attributes at assembly level but there is no AssemblyInfo.cs for .netCore

Any input here will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may want to approach addressing it from the commandline execution and and add an Exclude parameter with the file names that you don't want included.

Comment: I tried doing that but the problem here is the excludeFile paramter works while running the test case, although the service reference is embeded in dll itself and I cannot exclude the entire dll.